# retaining result obtained in onActivityResult

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, adapter, onactivityresult

I have two activities, one HomeActivity and one InfoFetchActivity. HomeActivity calls InfoFetchActivity for result as follows :

```
Intent infoIntent = new Intent(this,InfoFetchActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(infoIntent, 2);
```

Now, in InfoFetchActivity, i have a button which fetches the value of A editText and spinnerItem and sets the result for the callingActivity as follows:

```
Button btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
   btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           EditText classView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userClassName);
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.putExtra("INST_NAME",instValue[0]);
           intent.putExtra("CLASS_NAME",classView.getText().toString());
           setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
           finish();
       }
   });
```

This result is successfully obtained in my HomeActivity and Using the result obtained I m updating my ListView Items.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_list);
    classNameRecd = data.getStringExtra("CLASS_NAME");
    instNameRecd = data.getStringExtra("INST_NAME");
    if(requestCode == 2){
        icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.itemIcons);
        updatedTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itemHeadings);

            //getting the data
            updatedTitles[0]=classNameRecd;
            updatedTitles[1]=instNameRecd;



            SparseArray<MyListItem> finalList = new SparseArray<>();
            final ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_list);

            //update the list
            for(int i=0;i<updatedTitles.length;i++){
                MyListItem tempItem = new MyListItem(icons.getDrawable(i),updatedTitles[i]);
                finalList.append(i,tempItem);
            }
            //setting adapter
            myListAdapter myAdapter = new myListAdapter(this,updatedTitles,icons,finalList,findViewById(R.id.left_drawer),mDrawerLayout);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        }
}
```

The problem is...
I have to launch the InfoFetchActivity just once for getting the result Once. The Activity should not be visited again.
For this I used SharedPreferences :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("INST_NAME",instValue[0]);
    intent.putExtra("CLASS_NAME",classView.getText().toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

    finish();



} else {
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
    ed.apply();
}
```

On the first Launch i.e when the InfoFetchActivity is started first time, the result is as desired and all works fine. But when i reopen the app, the first two items updated in the list are empty.
Please suggest me how can i retain the values obtained in onActivityResult so that i do not have to set result again and again.

P.S : This is my first question on SO. Please do not mind the long question. Thanks in advance. Cannot post screenshots due to less reputation.

**UPDATE**: It was my silly ignorance. I forgot to declare my result in InfoFetchActivity as static. 
Also, i set my result in both sharedPrefs and in my buttons clicklistener. Thank you.

```
private static String className;
private static String instName;
```

Comment: Why don't you save those items as SharedPreferences too, then read them back on launching the app?

Comment: If suppose i save those items as SharedPreferences too, then the result which is passed is empty. Isn't there any way where once result is received in onActivityResult, it becomes available in the whole Activity class?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the result which is passed is empty'? When opening app, check those values, if they are not there, you know the app runs for the first time, so when in InfoFetchActivity, save those values. Next time, when app runs, these values will be there, and any activity can read them...

Comment: I'll give it a try. Will update the question if i am up with answer.